# Table in Outlook does not display text in the center

Tags: html, css, html-table, outlook, html-tbody

I use a table for my newsletter in outlook. Everything works until it comes to the text. My text is in outlook not in the center and is just on the left site.

**the problem:**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="footer" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="two-column" style="padding:0;text-align:left;font-size:0; background-color:rgb(189, 33, 68);"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                                                                <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; text-align: center;">
                                                                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#333333;background-color:rgb(189, 33, 68);" width="100%">
                                                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                                                                <tr>
  <![endif]--></td>
                                                <td class="inner" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px; font-size:0">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#333333;width:100%;font-size:11px;text-align:left;text-decoration: none;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="padding: 0px;"><font color="#FFFFFF">Um den Newsletter abzubestellen,</font> <a href="foo" style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; text-decoration: underline;"><font color="#FFFFFF">klicken Sie hier.</font></a><br />
                                                            <br />
                                                            <font color="#FFFFFF">F&uuml;r R&uuml;ckfragen wenden Sie sich bitte an <a href="foo" style="text-decoration:underline; color: #ffffff;">foo</a>foo<br />
                                                            E-Mails an den Abssender dieser Nachricht werden nicht bearbeitet.&nbsp;<br />
                                                            <br />
                                                            Ipsum lorem</font></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

**View in outlook:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug in my code.

After the closen table tag in my code is this td:

```
</table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
           </td>
               <td width="50%" valign="top">
               <![endif]-->
```

I changed the width from 50% to 10% and it works now.